# How to fix "Assembly "AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.605" error on executing JMeter Script?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a JMeter load test script for .Net Version 4.8 framework. It's successfully passed but on re-execution or on increasing thread group count it throws an error like "Assembly "AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" does not contain a script with hash code "de1feab2"." in View result Tree in JMeter.

Please let me know the exact steps to get it fixed for successful execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass view state value and ScriptManager’s hidden value while reposting it in .Net.

Below article may help u..
https://devio.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/configuring-jmeter-for-asp-net-sites/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already handled ViewState and EventValidation. Also the created test script is working fine for thread group count 1. Can you please help me with steps to maintain the ScriptManager's hidden value as it's value is static in all the created steps in a script. Please reply asap. Thanks.

Comment: I need an immediate solution to the mentioned problem statement.